# UV mapped textures not affected by lights

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, light

I have imported a .3ds model into my scene, and applied the textures which are UV mapped. The model renders ok except it is not affected by any lights I place in the scene.

I would like to have a number of lights and the shading of the model to look as it should. Is this not possible with such textures?
When rendering with 'foreground' selected the result is very dark as shown:
[image: Foreground render too dark]

When I render with 'background' selected this is the result:
[image]

I have a sun above the model and a hemi lamp very close to the right-hand wall but this seems to have no effect.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Here is a link to the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qujhazkc668r64q/Test%201%2014-08-14.blend

Comment: Post the Blend file

Comment: .blend file added :)

Comment: You don't have setup your materials... If you need me to explain, ask.....

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could explain it to me please!

Comment: I'm using someone elses 3ds model

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly fine question imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're not rendering the layer with your lamps.
Your model is on both layer 1 and 11, but your lamps are only on layer 11.

Go into the *RenderLayers tab*, select the foreground renderlayer and select layer 11 under *Layer*:

[image]

Comment: This seemed to do the trick, many thanks!